# I want to derive a column for sql table. Can someone tell what would be the best possible scenario or workaround for this

Tags: sql, mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

consider following table

```
ID.     ACCT_ID     GEO     IND     Timestamp
abcd    XEMXOAA5    IN      Y       2023-05-04 10:08:51.000

efgh    XEPPKAAX    IN      Y       2023-05-04 10:08:51.000
ijkl    XEPPKAAX    CA      N       2023-05-04 10:08:51.000
mnop    XEPPKAAX    ALAC    N       2023-05-04 10:08:51.000

qrst    XEMXOAB5    CA      Y       2023-05-04 10:08:51.000

uvwx    XEMXOAD7    EMEIA   Y       2023-05-04 10:10:43.000
yzab    XEMXOAD7    APAC    N       2023-05-04 10:08:51.000
```

in my scenario the ind column is not there I want to derive that column,
such that

1. when geo is IN then Y,
2. when same acct ids have different geo then in that IN should have y and others should have N as IND col under same acct id,
3. when there is no IN entry then it should have Y as ind,
4. when there is no IN entry and have 2 entries for same acct then it should consider latest timestamp with Y ind and other as N.

I tried various scenarios with window function, case when and row number but didn't get it
below is the one I tried but I know it is wrong.

```
select
ID,
ACCT_ID,
GEO,
case when geo = 'IN' then 'Y' 
            when geo <> 'IN' then 'N'
            when geo not in ('IN')  row_number() over(partition by acct_id order by Timestamp desc) = 1 then 'Y'
            else 'N'
END AS IND,
Timestamp
from test_table
```

Comment: Do not attach images, leave the table as text

Answer (score 0):

The rules are a bit confusing, but I think this will do it:

```
WITH flags AS (
SELECT 
    acct_id, 
    COUNT(*) AS acct_rows, 
    MAX(timestamp) as max_ts, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN geo = 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_geo_in
FROM tbl
GROUP BY acct_id
)
SELECT 
    x.*,
    CASE 
        -- if there's only 1 row, then it's Y whether geo is IN or not, according to rules 1 and 3
        WHEN acct_rows = 1 THEN 'Y'
        
        -- There's more than one row for this account, and according to rule 2:
        WHEN has_geo_in > 0 THEN CASE WHEN geo = 'IN' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
        
        -- There are no rows with geo=IN for this account, and according to rule 4:
        WHEN timestamp = max_ts THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
    END AS ind
FROM tbl x 
    INNER JOIN flags y USING (acct_id)
;
```